# Python, Speech Recognition stuck at 'Listening...'

Tags: python, speech-recognition

The code is stuck at listening ( `audio=r.listen(source)` line) and doesn't go beyond it. No error messages or anything else.

My code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def takeCommand():
    '''
    It takes user's voice as input
    '''
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio=r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Recognizing...")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
    print(f"Recognized Command: {query}")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("I didn't recognize what you said please repeat")
    return "None"

return query


takeCommand()
```

Comment: Please debug your code and find which line is the problem. If you don't have a debugger, simply insert a print("XYZ") after lines `r.pause_threshold = 1` and `audio=r.listen(source)` to detect the line.

Comment: Any code below this line isn't executing. "audio=r.listen(source)".

Comment: Your question isn't a good question (bad title, bad text, ...). Please have a look at [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask good questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, I'll surely work on it and try to improve. Being new to this platform my question may sound bad, but my problem is real.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just checked the [link](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#using-listen-to-capture-microphone-input) you posted in the comment.

There is this code:

```
with mic as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

If this code does not work, one reason could be that the microphone picks up too much ambient noise.

The solution may be

```
with mic as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with this library; but I think `r.listen(source)` is a blocking function (method). A blocking method is a method that blocks code from continuing execution until it is done (returned). Your app is waiting for `r.listen(source)` to finish.

You should put `print("Recognizing...")` before it. Also as I read [here](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/), `r.listen(source)` will return result (finish) when it detects silence (probably after a voice). So your code should continue execution after it detects silence.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is you have to set some arguments in the `listen()` method.

For example:

```
audio=r.listen(source,timeout=8,phrase_time_limit=8)
```